# Where do I find the data related to Campaigns in the Sitecore's SQL database?

Tags: salesforce, sitecore, salesforce-lightning, sitecore9, sitecore-xdb

I'm trying to sync the Salesforce campaigns to xConnect using the Sitecore's predefined pipeline batch (Salesforce Campaigns to xConnect Sync).

From the logs, I find that the data is successfully fetched from the Salesforce. 
This is the log when I run the pipeline batch -

```
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:17 INFO  [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline batch processing. (pipeline batch: Salesforce Campaigns to xConnect Sync)
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:18 INFO  [Data Exchange] Condition added to read objects modified on or after 12/31/2017 6:30:00 PM. (pipeline: Read Campaigns from Salesforce, pipeline step: Read Salesforce Campaigns, pipeline step identifier: 30c88b95-9c9b-4cac-94b8-a2d2061cf3db, object: campaign)
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:19 INFO  [Data Exchange] Definition batch was successfully submitted. (pipeline: Process Single Campaign, pipeline step: Add Reference Data Definition to Batch, pipeline step identifier: 79164044-afc0-4a41-84d3-4273534497d3, thread id: 0, batch size: 5)
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:19 INFO  [Data Exchange] Definition batch was successfully submitted. (pipeline: Read Campaigns from Salesforce, pipeline step: Submit Reference Data Batch, pipeline step identifier: 462073f0-9227-4589-8e2c-fd1de1822877, thread id: 0, batch size: 1)
```

But I couldn't find the data either in the reporting database or in the Experience analytics section of the Sitecore instance.
Where can I exactly find the synced data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Marketing Control Panel application and expand the "Campaigns" item to see all defined Campaigns.

The Campaign Creator application on your Dashboard should also let you search for them (see documentation here: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/campaigns.html

You can also find the raw items that should be created using the Content Editor and navigating to the Marketing Control Panel: /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Campaigns

Comment: Hi,
The problem is that I'm not able to find the data related to campaigns that are synced from Salesforce. But the logs show that the data is successfully synced. I have attached the log the question.